# How to include specific fields from embedded document without affecting parent document?

Tags: mongodb

How can I include specific fields from an embedded document without affecting the fields in the parent document?

From the Mongo documentation located here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-specific-fields-from-embedded-documents

With an input of:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    user: "1234",
    stop: {
      title: "book1",
      author: "xyz",
      page: 32
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    user: "7890",
    stop: [
      {
        title: "book2",
        author: "abc",
        page: 5
      },
      {
        title: "book3",
        author: "ijk",
        page: 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You can select only the "title" field of the embedded document with:

```
db.bookmarks.aggregate( [ { $project: { stop: { title: 1 } } } ] )
```

But that also excludes the "user" field from the parent document. The results are:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "stop" : { "title" : "book1" } }
{ "_id" : 2, "stop" : [ { "title" : "book2" }, { "title" : "book3" } ] }
```

Note that I don't know all of the fields in the parent document so I can't explicitly include them and I don't know all of the fields in the embedded document so I can't explicitly exclude them.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

Unfortunately, I do not believe there is a very clean way to accomplish this, considering the fields are not known.

The closest I could get was to also include the entire document in the query, then remove the original "stop" field. This means the original root document data that is returned will be in a field called "document".

I know that isn't exactly what you are looking for but it is as close as I could get.

You could maybe try to introduce `$replaceRoot` to make that new "document" prop become the new root again?

Check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZoqBLOmvT7K)

#### Database

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    user: "1234",
    stop: {
      title: "book1",
      author: "xyz",
      page: 32
    }
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    user: "7890",
    stop: [
      {
        title: "book2",
        author: "abc",
        page: 5
      },
      {
        title: "book3",
        author: "ijk",
        page: 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "stop.title": 1,
      document: "$$ROOT",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "document.stop"
    ]
  }
])
```

#### Result

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "document": {
      "_id": 1,
      "user": "1234"
    },
    "stop": {
      "title": "book1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "document": {
      "_id": 2,
      "user": "7890"
    },
    "stop": [
      {
        "title": "book2"
      },
      {
        "title": "book3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## Original

If I am understanding this correctly, you should just need to project the entire `stop` field.

Something like:

#### Query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      stop: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but that returns all fields from stop and still removes fields from the parent. I want all fields from the parent and only title from stop.

Comment: ahh ok that makes more sense. give me a couple of minutes and I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JohnVottero please see my updated answer.